# Populate dropdown of a Thymeleaf div using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, thymeleaf

I have a div like this

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="notebooksDropdown">
    <select class="form-control" id="notebooks" name="notebooks">
        <option th:each="notebook : ${notebooks}" th:value="${notebook}" th:text="${notebook}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I make an ajax call to get notebooks like this

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   contentType: "application/json",
   url: "/getNotebooks",
   ...
   success: function (data) {
        ...
        //notebooks is the array with which I wish to populate the dropdown
        //this works fine
        for(i in notebooks){
            var options="<option value="+notebooks[i]+">"+notebooks[i]+"</option>";
            $(options).appendTo('#notebooks'); 
        }
   }
```

But is there no way I can refresh the dropdown div tag after somehow setting the $notebooks in ajax, so that the options are populated by th:each instead of the way I'm doing it. something like:

```
//set $notebooks so the dropdown div can do its thing -> ??
//then refresh only that div
$( "#notebooksDropdown" ).load(window.location.href + " #notebooksDropdown" );
```

I'm a backend java developer and very new to (js, jquery, thymeleaf), so any help is valuable.

Comment: Not an answer - just some pointers: Thymeleaf template rendering, as you know, is a server-side technology. So, I think your ajax call would have to send parameters indicating what Thymeleaf [fragment](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#including-template-fragments) to use (for the drop-down HTML), and what data to provide in the Thymeleaf model - based on a related client-side selection by the user (to create your notebooks array). The ajax response would then be HTML not JSON. Disclaimer: I have never used Thymeleaf in this way. But it should work.

Comment: thanks @andrewjames. I thought I could set ${notebooks} in my js code after the ajax call. but later realized that ${notebooks} is thymeleafs way of request.getAttribute("notebooks"). which we know gets resolved at serverside, So answer to my question is we cant populate/alter/(even access) $variables in clientside js.

Comment: that does works only the request will be either `get` or `post` .

Answer (score 0):

${notebooks} is thymeleafs way of request.getAttribute("notebooks"). which we know gets resolved at serverside during compilation of the page itself, So answer to my question is we cant populate/alter/(even access) $variables in clientside js.